# Why do I have Description-Content-Type: UNKNOWN

Tags: python, python-packaging

I recently discovered a new metadata in my `.egg-info/PKG-INFO`: `Description-Content-Type`.

When I run:

```
python setup.py egg_info
```

I get:

```
Description-Content-Type: UNKNOWN
```

For instance, how can I tell that I use Markdown (`text/markdown`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The metadata field `Description-Content-Type` was introduced in [setuptools v36.4](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html?highlight=Description-Content-Type#v36-4-0) (on Sept 2017). It is available in the [Core Metadata v2.1](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/#description-content-type).

You can use this metadata in you `setup.py` to specify the content type of your package [Description](https://packaging.python.org/specifications/core-metadata/#description).

The classic usage is to fill the `long_description` with the README file of your project.
Then, you can use the `long_description_content_type` parameter to set the content-type.

The long description of your project is displayed in [PyPi](https://pypi.org/) (the Python Package Index).
You can read the PyPA article: “[Including your README in your package’s metadata](https://packaging.python.org/guides/making-a-pypi-friendly-readme/#including-your-readme-in-your-package-s-metadata)”.

Here is an example:

```py
import io

from setuptools import setup


def read(filename):
    with io.open(filename, mode="r", encoding='utf-8') as fd:
        return fd.read()


setup(
    name="YourProject",
    version='1.2.3',

    description="One line description of your project",
    long_description=read("README.rst"),
    long_description_content_type='text/x-rst',

    ...
)
```

You can choose one of those content types:

- `"text/plain"`: for simple text (eg.: "README" or "README.txt"),
- `"text/x-rst"`: for reStructuredText (eg.: "README.rst"), or
- `"text/markdown"`: for Markdown (eg.: "README.md").

**Note:** the support of Markdown is recent (you need setuptools >= 38.6).

Additionally, you can use [twine](https://pypi.org/project/twine/) to check the long description of your package (once the distribuable is built). For instance:

```sh
twine check dist/*
```